# Error with Entity Framework and Postgresql

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-6

Error message:

[[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVt4t.png)]

I am using Entity Framework with Postgresql. When I want to list record from my database, the program gave this message. I have checked web.config, my connection string which is created by an entity framework is different from other projects' connection string.

web.config

[[web.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeJtq.png)]

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="projeEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.EntityFrameworks.ProjeModel.csdl|res://*/Models.EntityFrameworks.ProjeModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.EntityFrameworks.ProjeModel.msl;provider=Npgsql;provider connection string=&quot;Host=127.0.0.1;Database=proje;Username=postgres;Password=sdt2018;Persist Security Info=True&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I think this is wrong but, I did not any changing

Comment: You should try a connection string with the same format as your other ones which work.

Comment: Don't post code and error messages as images, instead put the relevant text here directly with the appropriate format.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the providerName="Npgsql" if you are using https://www.npgsql.org/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this below code in your web.config file under system.data tag

```
<DbProviderFactories>
  <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" support="FF" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```